# is it possible flowplayer first play with html5 then flashplayer

Tags: html, flowplayer

My videos are in amazon and i want to play this video by flowplayer or jwplayer.But my requirement is the video first try to play in html5 if it not possible it will go for flash mode. 
I need a combination of HTML5 embed code and Flash embeded code.The embed code will automatically detect if the requesting device can play HTML5. If so, it will serve that code. If not, it will serve Flash version

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been sometime since this question was asked, but in case anyone else is looking for the answer you can try

```
<video width="VIDEO-WIDTH" height="VIDEO-HEIGHT" controls preload="auto">
<source src="VIDEO-PATH.m4v"  type="video/mp4">
<source src="VIDEO-PATH.ogv" type="video/ogg">
<object class="aligncenter" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" width="560" height="315">
    <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <param name="flashvars" value="config={'clip': {'url':'VIDEO-PATH.m4v','autoPlay':false, 'autoBuffering':true }}">
    <p>Your browswer does not support video...</p>
</object>
</video>
```

Replace “VIDEO-WIDTH” and “VIDEO-HEIGHT” with the video dimensions, and replace “VIDEO-PATH” with the full URL of the video, and you’re good to go.

One important note: mp4/m4v video files will not play in Firefox. And if you use the HTML5 video tag, Firefox also won’t fallback to Flash, either. It will just show a blank box. You need to include an ogv file format in addition to mp4.